# React Typescript project problem have Redux-Toolkit userSlice role problem

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

Property 'role' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<{ username: string; password: string; }>'.ts(2339)
any

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = [
  {
    "username" : "cavidan",
    "password" : "123123"
  }
]

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser(state, action) {
      const existingUser = state.find((user) => user.username === action.payload.username);
      if (existingUser) {
        existingUser.role = action.payload.role;
      } else {
        state.push(action.payload);
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { setUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not explicitly type your state then the state type is inferred from the `initialState` value passed to the slice, which in this case is an array of objects with only `username` and `password` properties.

Update the state to have the correct type.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type User = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  role?: string; // <-- optional role property
};

const initialState: User[] = [ // <-- array of User objects
  {
    username: "cavidan",
    password: "123123"
  },
];

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser(state, action: PayloadAction<User>) { // <-- type the payload
      const existingUser = state.find(
        (user) => user.username === action.payload.username
      );

      if (existingUser) {
        existingUser.role = action.payload.role;
      } else {
        state.push(action.payload);
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you rephrase the question a little bit? But from the code you provided, it appears that role was not included in the initialState but you're trying to access it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).